# pandas dataframe filter rows by specific substring in cell string position

Tags: python, pandas, string

```
df = C1  C2.  C3
     a.  abcde a
     b.  becde b
```

I want to take only rows where the position [1:3] in the column C2 in 'bcd' so in this case only take

```
df = C1. C2.  C3
     a.  abcde a
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean both letters at position `1` and `2` are in `bcd`?

Comment: @QuangHoang I mean the for st == abcde, st[1:3] == 'bcd'

Comment: `df.loc[df['C2'].str[1:4] == 'bcd']`.